# Laravel refresh page on database's record update with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I've got a mySQL table with 4 columns.One of them is updated_at() from timestamps().
Anyone got any idea how can i detect when the updated_at column changes and update one certain page with ajax?

I know that a better way to do it is a web socket but for my project is a little overkill.The project is on **laravel 5.2**

Answer (score 2):

You can detect when model updated using [Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events)
But I have no idea how to refresh html page from your PHP script without web sockets.

**EDIT**

try

```
Route::get('checkIfModelUpdated/{id}', function($id) {
    $model = YourModelClass::find($id);
    $updatedAt = Request::get('updated_at');
    return json_encode($model->updated_at->gt($updetedAt));
});
```

and client code

```
setInterval(function() {
       $.get('/checkIfModelUpdated/'+YOUR_MODEL_ID,
       {updated_at: LAST_UPDATED_AT},
       function(data) {
           if (JSON.parse(data) == true) 
                // refresh your page
       });
   }, 1000);
```

Comment: so how is an answer?

Comment: GIve me some time to test it...I am a bit newbie with ajax

Comment: be careful, I am fall asleep right now, so may be a lot of bugs in code

Answer (score 1):

Without web sockets, the only way is to have a Javascript `setInterval` running on the background and running ajax calls to your Laravel API. The API would check if any changes and respond with the updates, which will be received by your ajax call back and applied to the page.

Comment: `setInterval(ajaxCall, 300000);

function ajaxCall() {
}`

Something like this and i will check in ajaxCall() function if mysql column haschanged value?

Comment: Exactly, something like that. Your API should check the database for changes and respond with any changes that you may want to update in your page.